# Angular 5 forms creating a model for the form group inputs or leaving it as generic variable with 2 way binding

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-reactive-forms

I am new to Angular, I don't understand why most courses or tutorials are using a model or interface for the data that is taken from a form, for me I found it working well (& easier) to use generic variable with 2 way data binding to fill it.

Can someone explain why we should define a model for the form data ?

I mean instead of using

```
  attorney: any = {
  };
```

usually the courses use this:

```
attorney: Attorney = {...}
//where the Attorney is a class defined with many parameters
```

You can find my working code below for this.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xkcgng?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can use `any` for any variable/field/parameter, the problem is if you do this you will not get any safety from the typescript compiler.

```
interface Attorney  {
    name: string
}
class Comp {
    attorney: Attorney = {
        Name: 'Test' // compile time error which is good
    }
}
```

If you use `any` you can access any field on the object, which can lead to errors,

```
    attorney: any= {
        Name: 'Test' // compile time error which is good
        age: 10
    }
    console.log(this.name + ' '+this.age.trim('0')) // will be a runtime error instead of a compile time one
```

Comment: Thanks @Titian , but beside that compile time safety , is it wrong practice to use a generic data type for the form ? is there any other serious issue? cause I searched everywhere & never found explanation for this, also I am validating the form so I feel safe using it this way without extra model

Comment: @AhmedElkoussy It's your choice, the primary selling point of typescript is compile time safety. At runtime types are erased so they should behave the same. But I recommend you use the model version. It will pay off in the long run.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helpful explanation

Answer (score 1):

There is no right or wrong way to do any of this. If you want to use a custom type, use a custom type. If you want to use `any`, use `any`.

Just understand that each approach has costs and benefits. @Titan makes a good argument for using a custom type. Let the compiler do all the work for you.

You should use the approach that makes the most sense to you. If you don't see any reason why not to use `any` for your use case, and it makes your life easier, then use `any`. When you come to a point where `any` is not well suited and a custom type would be better, then you can switch.

Or you can try both now and see which one you like better for the particular feature you are building.

---

That being said, in your StackBlitz example, you are mixing template-driven forms with reactive forms. If you are using the `FormBuilder`, do not use `ngModel` to bind to your properties for the same form object values... just use `formControlName` or something. When you are working with plain objects, then it makes sense to use `ngModel` because that is the only way you'll get the binding.

Comment: Thanks for illustration, now I find that way I used in the example to be easier, is there any concern with that mixing I am doing ? I felt it is making things quicker

Comment: Well my question to you would be "why?". You are not using the form group at all.. there are no validators on it, and you are not extracting values from it anywhere (I assume you'll use the `attorney` class property to extra the value when submitting). So what is the point in even using the `FormBuilder` here? My response to your question depends on your answer to this question.

Comment: Great, I will still add more validations on it, maybe with some custom error messages, I felt it is easier to use the ReactiveForms approach to allow this, it turned out strange but it works well, so I am very hesitant in changing it, btw I am using that FormGroup in a stepper (wizard) so it is easier to bind to the formGroup than making custom @Viewchild to check the form validity

Comment: I agree with the use of a form group. I use them myself. I am just wondering why you are binding to the attorney property *as well* as using the form group. What does that give you that a form group doesn't?

Comment: it is just due to me being beginner :) , I found it easier to use in the material stepper, but as you said I am refactoring it to use template driven forms instead , much cleaner , thanks bro